# NOTIFYICONDATA icon notification c++

Tags: c++, winapi, notifications, system-tray

I have an application which runs as a service, as well as a secondary application which monitors the service. The monitoring application exists in the system tray using `NOTIFYICONDATA`, which works fine.

What I am currently trying to do, is when the application notices that the services has stopped, I want to display a notification (similar to as if the battery is running low on a laptop). I am basing my code off of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx). The function I have to do this is as follows:

```
void CALLBACK checkit( HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, UINT timerid, DWORD dwtime ) {
    if ( isServiceRunning() ) {
        if ( nidApp.dwInfoFlags != NIIF_NONE ) {
            Log( "dwInfoFlags != NIFF_NONE" );
            nidApp.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_NONE;
            strcpy_s( nidApp.szInfoTitle, sizeof( nidApp.szInfoTitle ), "" );
            strcpy_s( nidApp.szInfo, sizeof( nidApp.szInfoTitle ), "" );
            Log( "%d", Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_MODIFY, &nidApp ) );
        }
    } else {
        if ( nidApp.dwInfoFlags != NIIF_WARNING ) {
            Log( "dwInfoFlags != NIIF_WARNING" );
            nidApp.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_WARNING;
            strcpy_s( nidApp.szInfoTitle, sizeof( nidApp.szInfoTitle ), "Service Stopped" );
            strcpy_s( nidApp.szInfo, sizeof( nidApp.szInfo ), "The " PROGRAM_NAME " service has been stopped. Any runs in progress have been terminated." );
            nidApp.uTimeout = 10000;
            Log( "%d", Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_MODIFY, &nidApp ) );
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called every five seconds. Using the logs, I am able to see that the `dwInfoFlags` is set properly, and `Shell_NotifyIcon` returns `TRUE`, however, no notification is displayed. I'm sure I must be missing something, but I cannot figure out what it is.

`nidApp` is defined at the top of the CPP file as `NOTIFYICONDATA nidApp;` as is setup as follows:

```
hMainIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, (LPCTSTR)MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1 ) );
nidApp.cbSize = sizeof( NOTIFYICONDATA ); // sizeof the struct in bytes
nidApp.hWnd = (HWND)hWnd;            //handle of the window which will process this app. messages
nidApp.uID = IDI_ICON1;       //ID of the icon that willl appear in the system tray
nidApp.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP | NIF_GUID | NIF_SHOWTIP; //ORing of all the flags
nidApp.hIcon = hMainIcon; // handle of the Icon to be displayed, obtained from LoadIcon
nidApp.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER_SHELLICON;
nidApp.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
nidApp.guidItem = myGUID;
strcpy_s( nidApp.szTip, sizeof( nidApp.szTip ), PROGRAM_NAME " Service Controller" );
Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_ADD, &nidApp );
Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_SETVERSION, &nidApp );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `nidApp.uFlags` to `NIF_INFO` to display notification. Right now you are calling `Shell_NotifyIcon` with the same flags as were used to create notification icon.

Comment: Thank you; I added this to the rest of the uFlags options and it is working now :)